# Pyserial error: could not open port

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I've been following this tutorial: https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-python-tutorial

`import pyserial` didn't return any errors, but when I run my python code, I get the following error:

```
SerialException: could not open port 'com18': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please, privide minimal code to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

I copy what you can read in the tutorial:

```
ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial('com18',9600)
```

Note: It is very important to mention the correct COM port name. It can found by using the Device manager on your computer.

When you have plugged your arduino, windows has chosen another COM number.

The port can be found directly in arduino IDE. It detects all devices connected on USB; but the IDE do not know which one is your arduino. In the menu tools / port you will see the list of COM on your computer.

If no COM is proposed, then you miss a driver for your card under windows --> google for it.

Comment: My device manager doesn't list any COM ports. I don't have administrator access, so that may be why. Any other way I can find the correct COM port?

Comment: @Anonymous, at least for newer versions of pyserial, you can type `python -m serial.tools.list_ports` into the command-line.